# Laravel - login messages

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, message

I'm currently working on Laravel 5.8 version and I'm using Laravel make:auth option. That created me login and registration and all I did i add a phone number. So this is how it is looking in my `register.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone Number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

So this section:

```
 @error('email')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
       <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
 @enderror
```

shows me span message if email has already been taken. So how can I do that `@error('phone')` for my phone? I coded in my `RegisterController.php` that my phone my be `unique:users`?
Please help me with this `@error` message!

Comment: This is done using Validation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: So how would you solve this? Where can I add error messages for phone

Comment: What do you have in RegisterController.php?

Comment: Thank you, i founded a solution !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This will check User Phone Number Like Email. It Will Allocate Unique user Phone Number**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
  {
   return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'required|unique:users,phone'
    ]);
}
```

**For Displaying Errors In Register Blade**

```
@error('phone')
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</span>
@enderror
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this to RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'phone' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```